# How to click checkbox "Play user interface sound effects" macOS Ventura with appleScript

Tags: applescript, audio, system-settings, ventura

On macOS Ventura it is not possible to click on the checkbox "Play user interface sound effects"

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        click menu item "Sound" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
        delay 1
        click checkbox "Play user interface sound effects" of group 0 of splitter group 0 of window "Sound"
    end tell
end tell
```

I get such an error:

[image]

How can I fix my script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me on OS Ventura.

```
tell application "System Settings" to activate

tell application "System Events" to tell process "System Settings"
    click menu item "Sound" of menu "View" of menu bar 1
    repeat until checkbox "Play user interface sound effects" of group 1 ¬
        of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 ¬
        of group 1 of window "Sound" exists
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Play user interface sound effects" of group 1 ¬
        of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 ¬
        of group 1 of window "Sound"
end tell

tell application "System Settings" to quit
```

Comment: Eee!)) Thank You very much! How do you know what it is "of group 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1"? Couldn't find info anywhere

Comment: In Automator.app, you can record your actions (Watch Me Do) so that everything you do in System Settings will be recorded 1 by 1.  When you finish recording, you can copy that recorded action of clicking that checkbox "Play user interface sound effects" to your clipboard and paste it into a Script Editor document and you will see the info you need.